# NoClassDefFoundError trying to use OpenCyc, what could be wrong?

Tags: java

I want to create cycAccess object to connect to the openCyc knowledge base, but I could not create this object. I got NoClassDefFoundError from this code... Plz anybody can help me ?    Following is my code....

```
public static void exampleConnectingToCyc() {
System.out.println("Starting Cyc connection examples.");
CycAccess access = null;
try {
  access = new CycAccess("localhost", 3602);
  System.out.println("Successfully established CYC access " + access);

  // The following code should only be called if you will be modifying the KB
  // and one should typically use a real user and more specific KE purpose.
  // This information is used for accurately maintaining KB content
  // bookkeeping information.
  CycConstant cycAdministrator = access.getKnownConstantByName("CycAdministrator");
  CycConstant generalCycKE = access.getKnownConstantByName("GeneralCycKE");
  access.setCyclist(cycAdministrator);
  access.setKePurpose(generalCycKE);

  // Do stuff with the connection here.

  // Note: The class CycAccess contains many of the
  // useful public methods for interacting with Cyc.

  // Note: Establishing a connection with Cyc is relatively expensive.
  // If you have a lot of work to do with Cyc over time, make a single
  // CycAccess object and use that everywhere.
} catch (UnknownHostException nohost) {
  // if cyc server host not found on the network
  nohost.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException io) {
  // if a data communication error occurs
  io.printStackTrace();
} catch (CycApiException cyc_e) {
  // if the api request results in a cyc server error
  // example: cannot launch servicing thread;
  // protocol errors, etc.
} catch (Exception e) {
} finally {
  // ensure that the connection is closed when finished
  if (access != null) {
    access.close();
  }
}
System.out.println("Finished.");
```

}

Comment: What line are you getting the exception at?

Comment: And what class isn't found?  Please post a full log of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError usually means that a class that was available at compile time isn't available at runtime. I suggest you check the classpath of your application in order to see if all required dependencies are in the classpath. Because most of this code uses JDK-provided classes, you should probably look at the dependencies required for the CycAccess and CycConstant classes.